# How do I enable compression on channels in Phoenix?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I've got a channel in phoenix that pushes out ~4KB of data, a lot of it highly repeating and was wondering if there was a way to turn on compression for that channel.

It looks fairly simple to do if I was working with a phoenix controller, but I haven't been able to find out if this is possible or documented somewhere for a channel.

Thanks a bunch.

Comment: I know gzip can be used for compressing static content (See endpoint.ex) not sure if this can be applied to the channel endpoint somehow?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can configure gzip compression for the responses from a particular endpoint.

```
config :app_name, AppName.Endpoint,
  http: [compress: true]
```

Answer (score 3):

As answered by Endersstocke setting `http: [compress: true]` in the endpoint config works, even for websockets. However there are some limitations:

Phoenix in its current version (1.3.0) or more specific: cowboy (1.1) only supports `x-webkit-deflate-frame` compression for websockets. From my tests I've seen that only Safari sends these requests header meaning on Chrome you will not experience any compression at all.

So if you want to have the `permessage-deflate` compression you will have to wait until Cowboy 2.0. See [docs](https://github.com/ninenines/cowboy/blob/a45813c60f0f983a24ea29d491b37f0590fdd087/doc/src/guide/ws_protocol.asciidoc)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps tangential to the question, but I landed here when looking for how to compress WebSocket messages of Phoenix LiveView. I learned that for the current Phoenix version, 1.7.6, compression can be configured at the `socket` level:

https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/Phoenix.Endpoint.html#socket/3-websocket-configuration

```
  socket "/live", Phoenix.LiveView.Socket,
    websocket: [
      compress: true
    ]
```

Credit to a post on the Elixir Forum: https://elixirforum.com/t/how-to-enable-compression-for-liveview-diffs/34027.